# I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for a matrix in assembly using mmap but it does not work

Tags: assembly, x86, dynamic-memory-allocation, mmap

I am having trouble with the syscall mmap to dynamically allocate memory for a matrix,%eax should return at the end of the call the memory address but it returns a big negative value and the program has segmentation fault. And I know that I can use malloc to do this but I have to use mmap. This is the code for the mmap call:

```
main:
pushl $n#number of columns/lines
pushl $formatS
call scanf
popl %ebx
popl %ebx

movl n,%eax
movl $0,%edx
mull n
movl $8,x
mull x
movl %eax, len

mmap:
#syscall mmap
movl $192,%eax#code for mmap
movl $0,%ebx
movl len,%ecx
movl $3 ,%edx#PROT_WRITE+READ
movl $0x22 ,%esi#flags,MAP_ANONYMOUS+PRIVATE
movl $-1, %edi#file d
movl $0, %ebp#offset, porneste de la 0
int $0x80

         
mov %eax,%esi#matrix address
```

I tried to put $1 for the file in %edi but eax returns -9 which from what I read it is a problem with the file and I saw someone say that with -1 it works. I don't get that error anymore but eax is a big negative number.

Comment: Big negative is not necessarily an error, only if it is **very** big (within 4096 of the top end). `mmap` may very well return addresses with the MSB set especially on 64 bit systems running 32 bit code.

Comment: The value that remains in eax is -134492160, I feel like it is not correct

Comment: That is `0xF7FBD000` and is an entirely plausible page aligned address. Error codes are all above `0xFFFFF000`. In gdb, stopped after `mmap` returns, you can do `p/a $eax` and that should then also appear in the output of `info proc mappings`.

Comment: It worked, segfault was caused by another thing that was not related to mmap, thank you for answering

Comment: When working with memory addresses you shouldn't think of values as signed, it just doesn't make sense. I'd argue that it doesn't make sense to think about them in base 10 either.